# Spring Integration SFTP inbound adapter does not filter

Tags: filter, sftp, spring-integration

I have been trying to get the sftp inbound adapter to use my custom filter, or even to use the filter that I provide in the options. For some reason it always ignores my filter. The pattern is really simple too, and does indeed match for the incoming file names, if the filter would ever get called.

Does anyone have any ideas?

```
<int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter id="cobaltInbound"
channel="dealerDataInboundChannelAdapterOutputChannel"
session-factory="dealerDataSftpSessionFactory"
filter="customInboundFTPFilter"
local-directory="${ftpOutputPath}"
remote-directory="outbound"
delete-remote-files="false"
preserve-timestamp="true"
charset="UTF-8"
local-filter="acceptAllFilter">
<int:poller cron="0 0/5 * * * *" max-messages-per-poll="10" error-channel="logger"/>
</int-sftp:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

The custom filter is basic for the most part:

```
public class GenericInboundChannelFilter implements FileListFilter {

    private Pattern pattern;

    public GenericInboundChannelFilter() {
    }

    public GenericInboundChannelFilter(String patternString) {
        this.pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    }

    @Override
    public List filterFiles(Object[] objects) {
        ArrayList filteredFiles = new ArrayList();

        if (pattern != null && objects != null && objects.length > 0) {
            Object entry = null;
            for (Object file : objects) {
                Matcher matcher;
                if (file instanceof File) {
                    matcher = pattern.matcher(((File) file).getName());
                } else if (file instanceof FileInfo) {
                    matcher = pattern.matcher(((FileInfo) file).getFilename());
                } else {
                    continue;
                }
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    if (entry != null) {
                        //compare the two entries
                        if (file instanceof File) {
                            if (((File) entry).lastModified() < ((File) file).lastModified()) {
                                entry = file;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (((FileInfo) entry).getModified() < ((FileInfo) file).getModified()) {
                                entry = file;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        entry = file;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (entry != null) {
                filteredFiles.add(entry);
            }
        }

        return filteredFiles;
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks ok based on the limited information you provided; I suggest you run it in a debugger, or add some diagnostic logs.

Comment: I figured I may need to add more info.

I am using Spring Int 4.1.2-RELEASE. 

The filter is actually defined in a bean called customInboundFTPFilter
I did actually add a logger channel, and bumped it up to debug level so that I could see everything that could possible be wrong. 

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" level="DEBUG" log-full-message="true" />

I however do not see any errors at all. It simply skips the filter and goes on to retrieve every file from the directory that I have specified. I did catch it downstream in a splitter, so I was able to see that it was pulling all files

Comment: I have also used filename-regex, and filename-pattern as well. All of these seem to get ignored.

Comment: Lots of people are using those standard filters with no problems so it's something else. I meant you should add debug logs to *your* filter to log (or `System.out.println()`) the file name, the pattern and whether the match was successful or not etc so you can debug what the problem is.

Comment: Ok. I am also using an actual debugger. It never stops in the filter at all. That is basically why it has been confusing.

Comment: Try debugging `AbstractInboundFileSynchronizer.synchronizeToLocalDirectory` which is where the filter is called from. As I said, many, many users are successfully using filters.